# Behavior of useMemo deps

Tags: reactjs

According to https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo, it says useMemo evaluate deps value with `Object.is()` function, so if deps values are non primitive like array or object, useMemo calculates the value every render.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-gianmarco-r2wngr?file=/src/App.js:0-653)

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const temp = { a: 1 };
  const [a, setA] = useState({ a: 1 });
  const [aa, setAA] = useState(1);

  const obj = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("obj");
    return { b: a.a };
  }, [a]);

  const obj2 = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("obj2");
    return { b: temp.a };
  }, [temp]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setA((prev) => ({ a: prev.a + 1 }))}>
        button {a.a}
      </button>
      <div>{obj.b}</div>
      <div>{obj2.b}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setAA((prev) => prev + 1)}>premitive {aa}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click either the first or second button, the console output `obj2`, which makes sense because variable `temp` is an object and useMemo calculate value every render.

However, When I click the second button, the console does not output `obj` even though variable `a` is an object state.

Why does it happen? I assumed the first useMemo also calculate the value every render, but somehow not

Comment: `Object.is(a, a)` will always return `true`, not `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so if deps values are non primitive like array or object, useMemo calculates the value every render

You're misunderstanding this part. For non-primitive values, `Object.is()` compares whether they're the same reference. So if you do `Object.is({a: 1}, {a: 1})` that will return `false`.

In this case though, `useState()` returns the same reference on the next render if it's not been modified, which is the case when you click the second button because clicking the second button does not modify `a`.

If you instead pass `{...a}` to `useMemo()`, which will create a shallow clone of `a`, the `useMemo()` will be reevaluated on every render.